# How to get the format(ex:jpen,png,gif) of image file (BufferedImage) in java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, file-extension, image-formats

i want to get the buffered image format or type of image using java,

```
 InputStream stream = request.getResponseStream();   
 BufferedImage image=  ImageIO.read(stream);
 LOGGER.info(image);
```

Comment: You want to be able to check the format? (e.g. jpeg png bmp)

Answer (score 15):

Refer the `javax.imageio.ImageIO.read()` code

This code originally implemented in groovy but translated into java so It may have a syntax error.

```
public String read(InputStream input) throws IOException {
    ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input);

    Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);
    if (!iter.hasNext()) {
        return null;
    }
    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) iter.next();
    ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
    reader.setInput(stream, true, true);
    BufferedImage bi;
    try {
        bi = reader.read(0, param);
        return reader.getFormatName();
    } finally {
        reader.dispose();
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This code might help you to get the extension of image

```
public static String getFormate(String ImageName) {

    return (ImageName.substring(ImageName.indexOf('.'),ImageName.length()));
}
```

In the above code first it searches dot(.) and with help of substring() it will return the extension

Comment: You've got many downvotes because no explaination how to get `ImageName` from `InputStream` was provided. Practically there is no solution